# Отсутствует перевод описания причины проведения конкурса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

В [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1192901/176217), для которого действует конкурс (актуально на момент создания текущего вопроса), отсутствует перевод шаблонной причины проведения конкурса:

> [image: up-tp-date answer]

Текущие конкурсные вопросы можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему изменилось окончание подобных фраз (была точка, стало двоеточие). Добавил необходимые переводы по аналогии с имеющимися:

> [image: bounty started]

Будет на сайте в новых версиях. Текущая rev 2020.11.2.37934